# DIfferent behaviour on Edge/Chrome and Firefox on save filename

Tags: php, google-chrome, sockets, firefox, fputs

I work on a project and i am facing a strange behaviour between edge/chrome and firefox. I'm trying to save a file with filename like ***file_[ip address]-[username].txt***.

Sending data from html page through ajax ..

```
...
<form id="frmChat" action="#">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>User:</td>
        <td>
          <input class="input-data" type="text" id="txtUser" name="user" size="20" value="" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <input class="input-data-submit" type="submit" name="send" value="Send Value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td>
            <input  type="text" name="message" id="txtMessage" size="20" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
...  
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    ...
    }
  });
...
```

I get my data to my php file as follows:

```
...
$postVars = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
extract($postVars); //contains $user, $message and some more fields
...
```

Then i try to save the file like

```
...
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."-".$user;
$msg = $userip."-".$message;

$fp=fsockopen($host,$port,$errstr,$errno,300)
fputs($fp,$msg);
fclose($fp);
...
```

So far so good eveything working as supposed to. But when i open the page from edge/chrome i get "**null**" as $user and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and when i open the page from firefox i get the $user and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] **correctly**.

So the saved file created on edge/chrome looks like: **file_-.txt**

And from firefox is like: **file_127.0.0.0-test.txt**

What am i missing here?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server? A form? Not sure how the choice of browser could affect the remote_addr value though, that doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: thank you for your reply.. i am sending through ajax from html file

Comment: Is it a HTML file loaded via `http://` or via `file://`? And please show the relevant code, in case there is anything strange.

Comment: i am testing it on my localhost wamp server

Comment: Ok. Show the HTML of the form where `data` comes from as well please.

Comment: Also, you put `type: 'post',
    ...`. What other options are set after that ...? Don't leave stuff out, in case it turns out to be significant.

Comment: Also, are there any errors shown in Chrome's console when you test this?

Comment: i edited and added my form. No there are no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Either the access provider uses a google proxy, or the visitor uses a google proxy, then you have to look in the variables `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`

**PS:** these variables can be changed easily by the client, so you can use them but they should not be considered reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i think you missing the point. The point is that when i open the page from chrome returns null as saved filename but from firefox returns the corresponding variables correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. All the trouble caused by the way each of browsers handles the localhost ip.

- The firefox returns the localhost ip:

> **127.0.0.1**

- The chrome/edge returns the localhost ip as:

> **::1**

So in later time the sanitation "nulled" my variable, and caused the problem. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: You said $user was null though as well? Not sure that can be explained by what you've written here?

Comment: Yes thats right. I don't know why that happened though. I think beacause during sanitation proccess nulled all the variable, and i thought falsely that $user was null as well.